# Chunk option eval=FALSE ignored when spinning R-script

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

Spinning the following code (by clicking compile report in Rstudio):

```
#+ eval = FALSE
This line should not be syntax-checked, but it is.
```

Returns this error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = TRUE) : 
  <text>:2:6: unexpected symbol
1: #+ eval = FALSE
2: This line
```

Knitting the equivalent Rmd-chunk works fine:

````
```{r, eval = FALSE}
Using Rmd, eval=FALSE disables the syntax-check, and does not error
````

I was expecting that I could spin a chunk syntactically incorrect code without getting an error (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/spin.html). Am I mistaken for expecting this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks. I've now clarified that it can be reproduced by clicking "compile report" in Rstudio.

Comment: What command is that button running? `render` or `spin`? Try spinning the document manually first.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks. The button runs `rmarkdown::render` which calls `knitr::knit` or `knitr::spin` depending on if input is `.Rmd` or `.R` (https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html). When I follow your suggestion and run the document using `knitr::spin`, I get the same error.

Comment: It's not documented, but `knitr::spin()` requires the input R script to be a valid R script ([technical detail here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/c874c171afa348e883485afcd0fb3bdff29a280d/R/spin.R#L69)). One workaround is that you quote this sentence (i.e., turn it into a string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, but a workaround is to quote the sentence :

```
# Syntax checked:
2+2 
#> [1] 4

# Not syntax checked:
"
2 a 
"
#> [1] "\n2 a \n"
```

(source: Yihui Xie's comment above at 28jun2022)